# Dynamic-multiple inputs with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, html

For a dynamic system, which is a "bag" and some "parts" in it, I am trying to make an edit-page. It should be able to get the bag and the parts. Getting the data from the backend is no problem, but saving it is.

I tried to give each "part"-Input field names like `name="parts[][partName]`, `name="parts[][internalNumber]` and so on, but the $_POST-Array has a strange structure of many arrays:

```
parts [
   [partName = "Test1"],
   [internalNumber = "111"],
   [partName = "Test2"],
   [internalNumber = "222"],
   ...
]
```

I think that relying on counting and dividing doesn't seem like a reliable method to me, especially because most of the inputs can be empty.

Working with fixed names, like "parts[0][...]", "parts[1][...]" would be kind of difficult because of the dynamic structure by adding, removing and editing the groups.

What would be the best way to get the data reliably?

[image: Screenshot of Website-Draft]

Comment: You're on the rigtht track, but you do need the index of the parts[] array to be the same among the related fields. However it does not need to be sequential, just unique. So you can create some sort of UID each time you add a part, and use the same UID for the index of the parts array in each field name.

Comment: @RobRuchte That looks like a good solution, never thought about it. Thank you!